# Matplotlib add legend to pandas color map

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe `df`, it has a column which I use to create a color code column for matplotlib this way

```
df['color-code'] = np.where(df['Community School?']=='Yes', 'blue', 'red')
```

I also create a separate dataframe to use without null values for plotting

```
sc_income = df[~df['Economic Need Index'].isnull() & ~df['School Income Estimate'].isnull()]
```

Then I plot it using

```
#make plot bigger
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (40,20)

#plot Economic Need Index vs School Income Estimate
scatter(sc_income['Economic Need Index'], sc_income['School Income Estimate'], c=sc_income['color-code'])
plt.xlabel('Economic Need')
plt.ylabel('School Income $')

plt.title('Economic Need vs. School Income')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Final plot looks like this

The legend that's needed though should specify blue means community school, red means not community school.

[image]

Comment: Not an MCVE, so not really clear, what to suggest. [But you can create custom legends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416749/8881141), although probably [this approach](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-with-legend) will probably be sufficient in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to colour point by groups. There are many ways to do it. Using `matplotlib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate data
n_obs = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'Community School?': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], size=n_obs),
                   'Economic Need Index': np.random.uniform(size=n_obs),
                   'School Income Estimate': np.random.normal(loc=n_obs, size=n_obs)})

# your data pre-processing steps
df['color-code'] = np.where(df['Community School?']=='Yes', 'blue', 'red')
sc_income = df[~df['Economic Need Index'].isnull() & ~df['School Income Estimate'].isnull()]

# plot Economic Need Index vs School Income Estimate by group
groups = sc_income.groupby('Community School?')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(40,20))

for label, group in groups:
    ax.scatter(group['Economic Need Index'], group['School Income Estimate'], 
               c=group['color-code'], label=label)

ax.set(xlabel='Economic Need', ylabel='School Income $', 
       title='Economic Need vs. School Income')
ax.legend(title='Community School?')
plt.show()
```

Or using `seaborn` and `pairplot` for example:

```
g = sns.pairplot(x_vars='Economic Need Index', y_vars='School Income Estimate', data=sc_income, 
                 hue="Community School?", size=5)
g.set(xlabel='Economic Need', ylabel='School Income $', title='Economic Need vs. School Income')
```