# How can I set color and marker in one parameter for scatter function in python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I try to use different colors and markers for a series of data based on their labels:

I wrote:

```
   for x,l in zip(X,labels):
        ax.scatter(x[0],x[1], 'xb' if l == -1 else 'or')
```

by 'xb' I mean the 'x' for the marker and 'b' for the color, but it doesn't work.

So I wrote it as:

```
for x,l in zip(X,labels):
    ax.scatter(x[0],x[1], marker='x' if l == -1 else 'o', c='r' if l == -1 else 'b')
```

What is the correct parameter without using two separate named parameters? Or any other trick to shorten the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have so far not seen an if-else construct in a plot function. I would change the labels list:

```
X = [(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 2), (4, 8), (5, 3), (6,1)]
labels = [-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = ["xb" if item == -1 else "or" for item in labels]

for x,l in zip(X, labels):
    ax.plot(x[0],x[1], l)

plt.show()
```

It is also worth noting that scatter and plot use different conventions for marker definitions. The shortcuts for plot don't work afaik for [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html), where size s, color c, and markerstyle m must be provided separately.

Comment: You supposed 'xb' works? It was actually my question for an alternative for `marker='x' and c='b'`

Comment: As I said, imho you can't use the marker format strings "xb" etc. with `ax.scatter`, only with `ax.plot`. If you want to use scatter, you have to split the labels, e.g., `marker = l[0], c = l[1]`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice you used `plot` and it works like `scatter` in this case.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that [you have to create a custom legend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416749/8881141) because each data point is interpreted as an independent series now.